# python3 pip broken. missing distutils

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been trying to get pip with python3 on WSL ubuntu 16.04 and have had no success. I have been running `sudo apt install --reinstall python3-pip`, but still have issues getting pip to work properly.

```
$ pip3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 14, in 
<module>
from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 23, in 
<module>
    from pip.locations import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/locations.py", line 9, in 
<module>
from distutils import sysconfig
ImportError: No module named 'distutils'
```

Similar with `sudo`

```
$ sudo pip3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
   from pip import main
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 14, in 
    <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 23, in 
<module>
    from pip.locations import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/locations.py", line 9, in <module>
    from distutils import sysconfig
ImportError: No module named 'distutils'
```

Also I noticed that I seem to have two versions of python3 installed:

```
$ ls /usr/lib | grep python
python2.7
python3
python3.5
```

Comment: You can always use `python3 -m pip` or `python3.5 -m pip`, where `-m` means "use module". It's great when you have multiple Python versions installed, in fact, I never use the naked `pip` or `pip3` commands anymore. It lets you specify the exact interpeter you want. If that interpreter does not have `distuils`, you may be in more trouble,  but typically this fixes the issues right up.

Comment: you could try `sudo apt-get install python-distutils`

Comment: It's the same version of python3 check python3 --version and python3.5 --version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Python 3 documentation, distutils apparently is not deprecated, BUT, my install of 2.7 has disutils, but 3.6 does not.
When I read:
https://docs.python.org/3/installing/
It seemed to say that distutils was being deprecated, but it was not worded clearly if they were talking about distutils or something else.

If anyone knows the definitive answer, please let us know.

Answer (score -1):

So after a lot of pain, I finally gave in. I had made things worse and corrupted my entire python3 installation. I had corrupted too many files trying to fix everything. I ended up uninstalling WSL/ubuntu and reinstalling clean. I made of backup a few things first.

Unfortunately, this seems to be the best option if you have really messed this up, like I did. Being more careful now, python3 is working just fine, with pip. Make sure you follow official docs when you install.